# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on reboot "suspending console(s)"

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, suspend

I am running Kubuntu 18.04 on a 2015 Macbook Pro 15 inch retina. Not dual-boot.

I had some sort of battery malfunction and the power died w/o warning. Apparently, the system tried to suspend itself but didn't get all the way through.

Now, every time I boot, it appears to be trying to suspend, but never gets anywhere.

```
Freezing user space processes ...
OOM killer disabled.
Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Using 3 thread(s) for decompression
Loading and decompressing image data
Image loading progress 0 - 100%
Image loading done
Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend) to debug.
```

And no matter how long I let it wait, it never gets past this point. I have to hold the power button down to try again.

I never get to a point where I can use an interactive terminal or any GUI.

I had a time getting to this point. My grub menu and terminal are also broken, but I can use the Mac firmware boot manager to boot into Ubuntu live. I have tried running boot-repair, but that fails. That is a separate problem, and not the focus of this post. However, I *can* edit my `grub.cfg` directly from there.

I edited the `grub.cfg` directly to boot into recovery mode. It is only in recovery mode that I see any output on the screen.

I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, and <kbd>F7</kbd>. I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Nothing I do can get me to an interactive terminal.

How can I kill this process and force a clean reboot?

Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out (at least partially). I added `noresume` as a kernel option, which allowed the system to reboot normally. I then cleaned my swap with `swapoff -a` and removed the `noresume` option and we are back to normal.

Comment: Thanks so much, I had the exact same problem with ubuntu 18.04 on macbook after the battery ran out. On reboot, the screen would go blank after entering the encryption passphrase.

I rebooted in recovery mode and saw it getting stuck with the message 'Suspending console(s)' which brought me to this answer.

In my case, I then rebooted again and on the grub menu, pressed 'e' to edit boot options.
I scrolled down to the kernel options (line with `vmlinuz` followed by options) and added `noresume`. This allowed me to boot successfully.